# Save history using NSCache/NSMutable Dictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have an app in which I am surfing a website. I need to keep the history of the html pages that I visit alongwith the timestamp. How can I use NSCache and NSMutableDictionary to save the history into my files/folders ?? I tried searching for any examples or tutorials whixh use NSCache or NSMutableDictionary.. but I was unable to find any such example on googling .. Thanks and Regards.

Comment: just url of webpage or save webpage data

Comment: i think just the url of webpage alongwith timestamp would suffice .

Comment: r u using webview for surfing

Answer (score 0):

Do this as NSMutableArray *arrHistory, NSDateFormatter *formatter as class variable and its property:

```
  [yourwebView setDelegate:self];
  arrHistory = [NSMutableArray alloc]init;
  formatter NSDateForteFormatter alloc] init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Use webView Delegate method:

```
  - (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
 {
     NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[[request URL] absoluteString],URL,[formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]],timestamp, nil];
     [arrHistory addObject:dict];
 }
```

Now u have array of dictionaries as each dictionary contains url and timestamp

Answer (score -1):

Here is a nice complete implementation of a URL cache:

https://github.com/RIKSOF/three20/blob/master/src/Three20Network/Sources/TTURLCache.m